# converting integer from 2 bytes

Tags: java, integer, arrays

First of all I have a couple hours experience with java, so if its a bit easy question sorry about that.

Now, I have a byte array with size 2  And I want to get corresponding integer value from it. I use little endian notation. Here is my code:

```
public static int convertInt(byte[] twoByte){
       //TODO
}
```

Is there anyone to help me ?

Comment: Two bytes can only store 65536 different values. What range of values do you want to store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return (twoByte[0] & 0xff) + ((twoByte[1] & 0xff) << 8)
```

gives the correct result, interpreting the two bytes as unsigned number.